# Reduce IdentityServer4 access_token length by removing claims in profile service

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, identityserver4

I am working on IdentityServer4 application. The generated Access_token length is becoming too lengthy due to the claim value added to the context.IssuedClaims. I tried to remove claim type called "entity" and it helps in reducing the access_token length. But its removing the claim from ClaimsPrincipal as well. Is there a way I can add this claim back to my ClaimsPrincipal so that I can access it from all my client applications? Currently I am invoking a separate API to get the claim back every time. Below is the code from my ProfileService where I am filtering the claim.

```
public async Task GetProfileDataAsync(IdentityServer4.Models.ProfileDataRequestContext context)
{
    var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(context.Subject);
    var principal = await _claimsFactory.CreateAsync(user);            
    //Retrieve all the claims associated with the user
    var claims = from claimsdata in principal.Claims select new System.Security.Claims.Claim(claimsdata.Type, claimsdata.Value);
    //Exclude claim type "entity" since its huge in numbers and causing access_token size to grow
    var claimsWithoutEntity = claims.Where(x => x.Type != "entity");
    context.IssuedClaims.AddRange(claimsWithoutEntity);
    var roleClaims = _roleService.GetRoleClaims(user);
    context.IssuedClaims.AddRange(roleClaims);
}
```

Comment: you might have to use the UserInfo endpoint to get additional claims which are now not able of your access_token. see https://code-maze.com/identityserver4-authorization/ Getting Claims Manually from the UserInfo Endpoint

Answer (score 1):

A different alternative to reduce the cookie size without modifying the access token is to create a SessionStore, and you can set it using the SessionStore parameter here:

```
}).AddCookie(options =>
{
   ...     
   options.SessionStore = new MySessionStore();

})
```

What does a SessionStore do?

See this picture, taken from one of my training classes:
[image]

Here's a sample in-memory store

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
using Serilog;
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SessionStore
{
    /// <summary>
    /// MySessionStore
    /// 
    /// Custom session store, to hold the tokens in memory instead of storing them inside the Cookie.
    /// 
    /// This provides an abstract storage mechanic to preserve identity information on the server while 
    /// only sending a simple identifier key to the client. This is most commonly used to mitigate issues 
    /// with serializing large identities into cookies.
    /// 
    /// TODO: 
    /// - Needs logic to remove older items, otherwise we might run out of memory here.
    /// - Use the MemoryCache instead of a dictionary?
    /// 
    /// Written by Tore Nestenius to be used in the IdentityServer in production training class.
    /// https://www.tn-data.se
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    internal class MySessionStore : ITicketStore
    {
        private readonly Serilog.ILogger _logger;

        private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, AuthenticationTicket> mytickets = new();

        public MySessionStore()
        {
            _logger = Log.Logger;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Remove the identity associated with the given key.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="key"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public Task RemoveAsync(string key)
        {
            _logger.Debug("MySessionStore.RemoveAsync Key=" + key);

            if (mytickets.ContainsKey(key))
            {
                mytickets.TryRemove(key, out _);
            }

            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Tells the store that the given identity should be updated.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="key"></param>
        /// <param name="ticket"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public Task RenewAsync(string key, AuthenticationTicket ticket)
        {
            _logger.Debug("MySessionStore.RenewAsync Key=" + key + ", ticket = " + ticket.AuthenticationScheme);

            mytickets[key] = ticket;

            return Task.FromResult(false);
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Retrieves an identity from the store for the given key.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="key"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public Task<AuthenticationTicket> RetrieveAsync(string key)
        {
            _logger.Error("MySessionStore.RetrieveAsync Key=" + key);

            if (mytickets.ContainsKey(key))
            {
                var ticket = mytickets[key];
                return Task.FromResult(ticket);
            }
            else
            {
                return Task.FromResult((AuthenticationTicket)null!);
            }
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Store the identity ticket and return the associated key.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="ticket"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public Task<string> StoreAsync(AuthenticationTicket ticket)
        {
            //Only add one at the time to avoid race conditions
            lock(this)
            {

                //Make sure the key is does not already exist in the dictionary
                bool result = false;
                string key;
                do
                {
                    key = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                    result = mytickets.TryAdd(key, ticket);
                } while (result == false);

                string username = ticket?.Principal?.Identity?.Name ?? "Unknown";
                _logger.Debug("MySessionStore.StoreAsync ticket=" + username + ", key=" + key);

                return Task.FromResult(key);
            }
  
        }
    }
}
```

I did write a blog post, talking more about the purpose of the session store and how it can improve security at:
[Improving ASP.NET Core Security By Putting Your Cookies On A Diet](https://nestenius.se/2024/01/22/improving-asp-net-core-security-by-putting-your-cookies-on-a-diet/)

Comment: I am trying to reduce the access_token length itself. Based on the number of identity claims the token length is getting bigger.

Comment: Yes, by using a session store as described above and not storing the tokens inside the cookie, the cookie will be very much smaller.

Comment: You also have to separate what goes into the ID-token and what goes into the access token. Exactly where do you have a problem with the access token size? in the client or in the API